# Cant set Action to UIBarButtonItem created on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following view on my storyboard. I'm trying to create an IBAction on the Send button by dragging and dropping it on my View Controller. Unfortunately the action is not being called.

[image]

So my action looks like this:

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("test")
}
```

What i also tried is to drag the bar item as an Outlet on my Controller and set the action programatically.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {        
    self.sendButton.target = self;
    self.sendButton.action = Selector("sendMessage:")
}

func sendMessage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("hue")
}
```

No log message is displayed. It just dont call the actions.

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: the action is not called.

Comment: Silly question, but is your .swift file linked to your TableView in Storyboard? That would result in no functionality if it weren't...

Comment: Yeah it is. If it wasnt i couldnt be able to link the UIBarButtonItem and the Controller. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out.

I must drag the UIButton inside the UIBarButtonItem not the UIBarButtonItem. So as you can see in the image bellow i was dragging the Item `Send Button` not the button `Send`.

[image]